# Why is the value being added in do-while loop meanwhile it should get out of the loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a simple program which asks the user about the age and based on that, it generates a total price at the end, but once the user inputs -1 - it should get out of the loop and display the result. The problem I'm having is that it counts the -1 entry into peopleCounter and the price too, how do I avoid that?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age = 0;
    int peopleCounter = 0;
    double totalPrice = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter the age " <<endl;
        cin >> age;
        if (age < 16) {
            totalPrice += 2.50;
        } 
        else if (age > 65) {
            totalPrice += 3;
        }
        else {
            totalPrice += 5;
        }
        peopleCounter += 1;
    } while (age != -1);

    cout << "Number of people is " << peopleCounter << " and the price is: " << totalPrice;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell your computer not to count it?

Comment: Side note: is the negative age (apart from -1) a valid input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the `do-while` as a `while`, and then prompt the user, get an input, and check the input's validity, all inside the `while` condition itself. This way, you never enter the loop if the `age` is `-1`:

```
while (cout << "Enter the age " << endl
       && cin >> age
       && age != -1) 
{
    if (age < 16) {
        totalPrice += 2.50;
    }
    else if (age > 65) {
        totalPrice += 3;
    }
    else {
        totalPrice += 5;
    }
    peopleCounter += 1;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/85ErTn).